# How to change value of parent element to an element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the css property of the "node"-class by clicking on the div inside of it which got the class "expand".

When I click on the "expand" div inside the "note", I want to go to parent "note" for changing it size:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var add = document.getElementById("add");
var notespace = document.getElementById("notespace");


var expand = document.getElementsByClassName("expand");
var notes = document.getElementsByClassName("note");


add.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var textValue = text.value;
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "<div class='note'>" + textValue + 
                  "<br/><br/><div class='expand'> Expand </div></div>";
    notespace.appendChild(p);
    text.value = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < expand.length; i++) {
        expand[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            notes[i].style.size = "3000px";
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: For the next time: Please make sure you pasted code is formated. This improves the readability of question or answer. Example to format code quickly: https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-beautifier.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to re-get the values of expand and notes, because after you add them to your html, the two variables expand and notes, dont know yet that you have added them and they don't contain them. ( you also have to removee the eventlistner otherwise you're gonna get a bugg at approximately twelve notes added :D because you will have too many eventListners on each element

```js
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    var add = document.getElementById("add");
    var notespace = document.getElementById("notespace");
    var expand = document.getElementsByClassName("expand");
    var notes = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
    add.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var textValue = text.value;
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = "<div class='note'>" + textValue + "<br/><br/><div class='expand'> Expand </div></div>";
        notespace.appendChild(p);
        text.value = "";

        for( var i = 0; i < expand.length; i++){
            const note = notes[i];
            expand[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
              note.style.size = "3000px";
              note.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            });
        }    
    })
```

```css
#notespace {
 width: 100%,
 height: 100%,
 background: grey,
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="add">add</button>
<input id="text"/>
<div id="notespace">


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i got an error:

expand[i].removeEventListner is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Voila!, I fixed the code and put it in a snippet, you don't need the removeEventListner after all it's not duplicated anyway.  the problem was that when the eventListnerwas clicked `i` had changed so i put the note in a const and now when the even is clicked, you it triggers the right note, I added background red to show that it's working but you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) attribute :

```js
for( var i = 0; i < expand.length; i++){
  expand[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.parentNode.style.size = "3000px";
  })    
}
```

Or the [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method :

```js
for( var i = 0; i < expand.length; i++){
  expand[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.closest(".note").style.size = "3000px";
  })    
}
```

Note that `closest()` [is not supported on IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#browser_compatibility).

Comment: his expand[i] will not even exist, because it's created dynamically, so his problème is not really about reaching the parent, but adding the evenListners to the newly created expand Elements

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but they don't seem to work. When i hover over them in vscode it says "any"

Comment: @MeddahAbdallah `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live HTMLCollection, not an array. Once appended to the document, the values in `expand` and `notes` will update.

Comment: @Randomcodingbeginner what do you mean by it does'nt work ? Have you tried to replace your `for` loop ? What is the error you get in the console if there is one ?

Comment: @Tom I didn't know that you taught me something thank you, I corrected my answer. however, I would prefer to show him the problem in his code rather than giving him a different solution, in his code node[i] does not, in fact, exist cuz when he clicks, `i` has changed already, that's the reason his code doesn't work, your code avoids this problem, which is fine, but I usually prefer not to impose a way of coding rather correct their own way.